# Jupyter notebook not launching from navigator or command prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Anaconda. I cannot get jupyter notebooks to launch from either the navigator or the command prompt. I'm working from windows 10. I've tried `jupyter notebook --debug` and get the following results.

```
[D 10:11:30.573 NotebookApp] Searching ['C:\\Users\\Zachary', 'C:\\Users\\Zachary\\.jupyter', 'C:\\Users\\Zachary\\Anaconda3\\etc\\jupyter', 'C:\\ProgramData\\jupyter'] for config files
[D 10:11:30.574 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 10:11:30.574 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in  C:\Users\Zachary\Anaconda3\etc\jupyter
[D 10:11:30.575 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\Zachary\.jupyter
[D 10:11:30.576 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\Zachary
[D 10:11:30.576 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 10:11:30.577 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\Zachary\Anaconda3\etc\jupyter
[D 10:11:30.577 NotebookApp] Loaded config file: C:\Users\Zachary\Anaconda3\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 10:11:30.577 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\Zachary\.jupyter
[D 10:11:30.578 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\Zachary
```

seems like its getting hung up somehow or not finding the files it needs. I've tried uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling and I'm having the same issues. Any suggestions to get jupyter notebooks working would be much appreciated.

Edit: I've gone to localhost:8888 and nothing is there.

Comment: Is that the entire output?

Comment: yes, that is the entire output.

Comment: Did you open your browser to `localhost:8888`?

Comment: Also, what are the contents of the file `C:\Users\Zachary\Anaconda3\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json`?

Comment: Here is what is in jupyter_notebook_config.json -- {
  "NotebookApp": {
    "nbserver_extensions": {
      "jupyterlab": true
    }
  }
}

Comment: I've gone to localhost:8888 and nothing is running there.